# Typescript definitions in wrong folder using rollup and typescript2

Tags: typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I'm building a package using React, Typescript, Rollup, rollup-plugin-typescript2.
While the generated JS files are fine, the generated definition files are in the wrong directory.

Current result:

```
MyLib
|_\lib
| |_index.js
| |_index.esm.js
| |_\src
|   |_index.d.ts
|   |_\components
|     |_Button.d.ts
|     |_WafeForm.d.ts
|
|_\src
  |_index.ts
  |_\components
    |_Button.tsx
    |_WaveForm.tsx
```

Expected result:

```
MyLib
|_\lib
| |_index.js
| |_index.esm.js
| |_index.d.ts
| |_\components
|   |_Button.d.ts
|   |_WafeForm.d.ts
|
|_\src
  |_index.ts
  |_\components
    |_Button.tsx
    |_WaveForm.tsx
```

This is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true })
  ],
  external: ['styled-components']
};
```

And my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

/lib/src - useless

I expect that `lib` folder should be equal `src` but should have *.js, *.esm.js and *.d.ts instead of *.ts(x)

```
MyLib
|_\lib
| |_index.js
| |_index.esm.js
| |_index.d.ts
| |_\components
|   |_Button.js
|   |_Button.esm.js
|   |_Button.d.ts
|   |_WafeForm.js
|   |_WafeForm.esm.js
|   |_WafeForm.d.ts
|
|_\src
  |_index.ts
  |_\components
    |_Button.tsx
    |_WaveForm.tsx
```

You can add `preserveModules: true` into `rollup.config.js` outputs

```
...

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      preserveModules: true, // <- here
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
      preserveModules: true, // <- here
    }
  ],
  ...
};
```